# How should I initialize some code in Nextjs 9.0

Tags: next.js

Using `create-next-app` create new project like this

```
npx create-next-app next9.1
cd next9.1
tree -I node_modules
├── components
│   └── nav.js
├── next.config.js
├── package.json
├── pages
│   └── index.js
├── static
│   └── favicon.ico
└── yarn.lock
```

create `/pages/api/index.ts` file then client can call `/api`

But I need query some data from mysql, Where and When should I initilize mysql pool without server.js (in nextjs precious version)

Answer (score -1):

Read below article from Zeit (Not updated to next9 but similar, just move api folder inside `/pages` so you can take advantage of Dynamic Routing and ES5+ )

https://zeit.co/guides/deploying-next-and-mysql-with-now

Comment: 3q for your comment, I know how to use them together. actually , I use mysql via ssh Tunnel , if init mysql connection in page/api, the first render is too slow,  so i want to know where can I trigger some code (some init task) after `next start`

Comment: Lambdas go idle as soon as there are no requests for a specific time (5 mins i think) so there is no point to do any initial task.
Waking up lambdas depends on the amount of dependancies you have. for a simple "hello world" the wake up time is around 500ms

https://mikhail.io/serverless/coldstarts/aws/

But you can do something else
- user goes to home page which requires no API calls
- do a dummy api call to wake up the lambdas before user navigate to pages that requires backend data.

Welcome to serverless world